# Динамическое добавление элементов на панель java

Tags: java, swing

Необходимо добавить на панель некоторое количество радиокнопок (количество задает пользователь). Варианты с видимостью не подходят. Подскажите как это реализовать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так не пробовал?

```
public static void main(String[] args) { //Создание Обектов 
    final JFrame form = new JFrame("RadioButton");
    final JButton button1 = new JButton("Добавить"); 
    form.setVisible(true);
    form.setSize(600, 800);

    final Panel panel = new Panel();
    button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JRadioButton b = new JRadioButton();
            panel.add(b);
            panel.validate();
        }
    });

    panel.add(button1);
    form.add(panel);
}
```

Comment: так не работает. еще выяснил что в конце надо добавить jPanel.validate(); но и это не помогло.

Comment: у меня все работаєт

Comment: можно более обширный пример кода

Answer (score 1):

храните у себя все радио в листе "List<JRadioButton>"

делаете метод addRadio, в котором делаете следующее:

```
// 1. для всех элементов листа удаляете их из панели  
// 2. добавляете элемент в список  
// 3. для каждого элемента списка добавляете его к панели  
// 4. репейнт панели
```

в принцыпе удалять/добавлять не обязательно, особенно если вам нельзя изменять их порядок.

p.s. а еще лучше не в списке а в хешмап чтоб можно было с ними работать по ID

Comment: вопрос как-раз в том, как добавить на панель элемент.

Comment: у вас количество элементов будет задаватся 1 раз или будет изменятся в зависимости от того что выберет пользователь?

Comment: количество элементов будет вводить пользователь во время работы программы, причем несколько раз.

Comment: ну если вам ненадо добавления/удаления всех элементов тогда этого должно быть достаточно:  

    panel.add(item)
    panel.repaint();

Comment: странно
private void jButton2MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent     evt) {
            jPanel4.add(new JRadioButton("1"));
       // jPanel4.validate();
        jPanel4.repaint();
    } 
Не работает(

Comment: А jButton2MouseClicked когда вызывается?

Answer (score 0):

Вообщем необходимо было задавать размеры нового элемента.
    JRadioButton f2 =new JRadioButton("hi");
    f2.setSize(50,50);
    f2.setLocation(10, 10);
    jPanel4.add(f2);
    jPanel4.revalidate();

Comment: Это потому что у вас нет лэйаута, вот и размеров по дефолту нет. И вообще, нет никакого смысла добавлять на форму радио-кнопки просто в воздухе..